# PHP Zend_mail gmail API email backup encoding problem

Tags: php, gmail, zend-mail

I am using three legged method to get email backups grom gmail inbox.
Im trying to store the gmail mail object string to file for email backup, saving it as .eml file. using the following code:

```
<?php
    for($i = $totalMessages; $i >= ($totalMessages-$pager) && $i <= $totalMessages; $i-- )
{
    $msg = $storage->getMessage($i);

    file_put_contents($i.".eml", $msg);
?>
```

I can not find necessary information in the mail when I see it in outlook or any other mail browser, niether the attachments are shown as they should appear, but the attachments are shown in base64 encoded as string.

[image: Cannot see any Subject,sender, recipient or attachment information]

[image: Unformated html showing instead of webpage]

[image: attached image as string]

I want to see them in mail browser as they should appear propperly, and later on restore email to inbox.
can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you tried to open the .eml-file with a text-editor and see what's inside? It looks like this is a valid encoded e-mail but if there is "additional" non e-mail data on the top this might "confuse" the e-mail parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the headers to the .eml file in order to show it in some email client(outlook etc.)

I did it the following way:

= ($totalMessages-$pager) && $i <= $totalMessages; $i--)
{
    $msg = $storage->getMessage($i);

```
$headers    =   "Date: " . $msg->date."\n"
                ."Delivered-To: ". $msg->to ."\n"
                ."Subject: " . $msg->subject ."\n"
                ."From: " . $msg->from ."\n"
                ."To: " . $msg->to ."\n"
                ."Content-Type: " . $msg->contentType."\n\n";


file_put_contents($i.".eml", $headers.$msg->getContent());
```

?>

Best of luck